# In Go, is it possible to perform type conversions on the multiple return values of a function?

Tags: go

```
type Node int
node, err := strconv.Atoi(num)

Foo(Node(node))  // Foo takes a Node, not an int
```

Is it possible to avoid the ugly "Node(node)" in the above example? Is there a more idiomatic way to force the compiler to consider node a Node and not an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing really elegant.  You could define an intermediate variable

```
n, err := strconv.Atoi(num)
node := Node(n)
```

or you could define a wrapper function

```
func parseNode(s string) Node {
    n, err := strconv.Atoi(num)
    return Node(n)
}
```

but I don't think there are any one-line tricks.  The way you are doing it seems fine.  There is still a little stuttering here and there in Go.

Comment: I think the wrapper function above would not compile b/c of unused `err`.

Comment: Right, but the original example isn't a complete working example either.  There is obviously stuff left out both places.

Answer (score 1):

No. Conversion converts an (convertible) expression. Return value of a function is a term (and thus possibly a convertible expression) iff the function has exactly one return value. Additional restrictions on the expression eligible for conversion can be found [here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).